# Apply autofilter using macro after worksheet has calculated?

Tags: vba, excel

So I've set up this spreadsheet at work - I end up having to do a lot of fiddly Excel tasks, though I barely know any VBA - and I want a table to automatically filter itself after the worksheet has been edited. The problem is that the column which is being filtered is full of formulas, which change in response to edits made by the user, and the filter gets applied before the column has finished calculating, producing erratic results. So really what I want is to apply AutoFilter after the worksheet has been calculated, rather than after it has been edited.

The macro I have been using is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Library").ListObjects("Library")
         .AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
    End With
End Sub
```

Naively changing the activating event to Worksheet_Calculate() doesn't work - it appears to be repeatedly applying the filter over and over again.

I'm sure this is a relatively simple one and I just don't know what it is I need to do. Can you guys advise?

(PS first time posting here - hope I have done everything right!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, have solved it myself. For anyone else with the problem, I just set calculation to manual and then replaced my code with:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Calculate   
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Library").ListObjects("Library").AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
End Sub
```